# How can I get non-standard day and hour text into an XDate object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, datetime

To explain the situation a little more; we have a **non-standard textual time and date string** that varies significantly and will need to be **parsed** into an `XDate` (http://arshaw.com/xdate/) object (likely multiple `XDate` objects).

Note that **I am not looking for someone to completely write the code**. Just some **theories and quick code snippets** to handle all of the possible situations (even for **failure**). Furthermore, this is **NOT a homework assignment**.

My first solution was using `split()` but failed miserably. A few other possibilities I looked into were `regex`, `pattern matching`, `loop text until not ascii`, `number picker from string`, etc.

Upon failure, I'll most likely just generate some random business hours.
**Avoiding failure is particularly important.**

I am not sure what the **best approach** would be. **Any and all help is highly appreciated.**

Here are just SOME possibilities. Each line represents one possibility.

**Dates and Times:**

- Mon 6 am - 8 pm
- Mon-Fri 6 am - 8 pm
- Mon, Wed, Fri 12 pm - 9 pm
- Mon-Thu, Sun 11 am - 8 pm
- Monday 12:00 PM - 10:00 PM, Tuesday 12:00 PM - 10:00 PM, Wednesday 12:00 PM - 10:00 PM
- Mon-Fri 10am-10pm, Sat 10am-1am, Sun 10am-9am, some random text
- mon 11:00am-12:00am, tue 11:00am-12:00am, wed 11:00am-02:00am
- monday 11:00-21:00, tuesday 11:00-21:00, wednesday 11:00-21:00
- mon 11:00am-8:30pm;tue 11:00am-8:30pm;wed 11:00am-8:30pm;thu 11:00am-8:30pm;

**Result:**
The output will be a `JSON` object of format:

```
{
    mon_open: "6:00 am",
    mon_close: "8:00 pm",
    tue_open: "6:00 am",
    tue_close: "8:00 pm",
    etc
}
```

Comment: With that variety of possible formats, you are asking for some kind of AI.

Comment: I was thinking some sort of formatter could work. (DAY-DAY h tt - h tt) kind of thing.

Comment: Well, if you’re thinking regular expressions, then I’d start with looking what possible patterns would match the different day and time formats in your examples … and then try to combine them.

Comment: I've had to tackle this in many ways, everything from "6 hours ago" to "Monday, Feb 14th, 08:44:10 +8 PDT" to "112387482842". Converting such dates, you will certainly need `regex` to make this as easy as possible. FYI, I've always had a pain in the a** with getting it mapped correctly. You best bet is to separate it into EVERY field you need, then concatenate the value.

Comment: You said they will need to be parsed into an XDate, but in the result they are only normal strings.

Comment: Just an idea, use datepicker/calender to make week-scheduler. Then you won't have to parse date strings you can easily get date ranges. Unless of course you have to use date strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more than 5 hours, I was able to complete this project (with the help of Derek). All but one instance pass my tests. On the single failed item, the end time shows up wrong. Perhaps someone else can see the error.

Here is the solution for anyone that might need it:

**Pre-requisits:**
Modified/Updated DateJS from: https://github.com/abritinthebay/datejs

**Gist:**
https://gist.github.com/bugs181/8819564

**JSBin:**
http://jsbin.com/EXeyeZI/5/edit?html,js,console

**Code:**

```
//var str = "monday-Thursday 9:00 PM - 12:00 PM, Tue 11:00 PM - 12:00 PM, Wednesday 10:00 PM - 12:00 PM"; // PASS
//var str = "Mon 6 am - 8 pm"; // PASS
//var str = "Mon-Fri 6 am - 8 pm"; // PASS
//var str = "Mon, Wed, Fri 9 pm - 12 pm"; // PASS
//var str = "Mon-Thu, Sun 11 am - 8 pm"; // PASS
//var str = "Monday 10:00 PM - 12:00 PM, Tuesday 11:00 PM - 11:30 PM, Wednesday 10:00 PM - 12:00 PM"; // PASS
//var str = "Mon-Fri 10am-10pm, Sat 10am-1am, Sun 9am-10am, some random text"; // PASS
//var str = "Mon-Fri 10am-10pm, don't break the days, Sat 10am-1am, Sun 9am-10am, some random text"; // PASS
//var str = "Mon-Fri 10am-10pm, !@#$%^&U* Sat 10am-1am, Sun 9am-10am, some random text"; // PASS
//var str = "mon 11:00am-12:00am, tue 11:00am-12:00am, wed 11:00am-02:00pm"; // PASS
//var str = "monday 11:00-21:00, tuesday 11:00-21:00, wednesday 11:00-21:00";// PASS
//var str = "mon 11:00am-8:00pm;tue 11:00am-8:30pm;wed 11:00am-8:30pm;thu 11:00am-8:30pm;"; // FAILED
var str = "monday-Thursday 10:00    PM - 11:00 PM, Tue 10:00 PM - 12:00 PM, Wednesday 10:00 PM - 12:00 PM"; // PASS

// Some useful variables.
var splitter = '$';
var short_days = new Array('mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun');
var long_days = new Array('monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday');
var open_name_days = {}; // Place to store business hours object.

// Make text all lower case and remove white space.
var str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\s/g, '');

// Match and replace any day abbreviations. Will match until non A-Z character.
var regex_days = /(mon|tue|wed|thu|fri|sat|sun).*?(?=[^a-z])/g;

var match;
while ((match = regex_days.exec(str)) !== null) {
  var match_day = short_days.indexOf(match[1]); // Returns a regex short_day.
  str = str.replace(match[0], long_days[match_day] + splitter); // Replace short_days with long_days in string.
}

// Replace any indicator for interval with + signs, which represent 'to'. Indicator will be assumed anything between start_day and end_day.
//str = str.replace(/-/g, '+');

// Split days by characters
var days = str.split(/[,;]/);
console.log(days);
console.log('');

// Loop through each day.
var len = days.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) { 

  if (!days[i]) continue;
  var day = days[i].trim();
  console.log('Day: ' + day);

  // Find the start and end day. Will match until not A-Z character.
  var regex_day = /(monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday).*?(?![a-z])/g;

  // Something broke, so continue onto next day. This is likely caused by random text not containing a day.
  if (!day.match(regex_day)) console.log('Something broke with regex_day');
  if (!day.match(regex_day)) continue;

  // Regex start_day and end_day from day.
  var start_day = day.match(regex_day)[0];
  var end_day = day.match(regex_day)[1];
  end_day = ((end_day) ? end_day : start_day);

  // Get indexes of start_day and end_day to be used later for days range.
  var start_day_index = long_days.indexOf(start_day);
  var end_day_index = long_days.indexOf(end_day);

  console.log('start_day: [' + start_day_index + '] ' + start_day);
  console.log('end_day: [' + end_day_index + '] ' + end_day);

  // Detect times from day string.
  var regex_time = /(\d\d:\d\d|\d{1,2})(am|pm)?/g;

  // Regex time from this day string, fallback to string before split.
  var time_match = day.match(regex_time);
  // Something broke, this is likely caused by no time information. Attempt to retrieve it from string.
  if (!time_match) { 
    time_match = str.match(regex_time);
    if (!time_match) continue; // Unrecoverable at this point, continue onto next day.
  }

  var start_time = time_match[0];
  var end_time = time_match[1];

  // Parse time from Date.js.
  start_time = new Date.parse(start_time).toString('h:mm tt');
  end_time = new Date.parse(end_time).toString('h:mm tt');

  console.log('start_time: ' + start_time);
  console.log('end_time: ' + end_time);

  console.log('');

  // Loop through days range and output to object.
  var len = short_days.length;
  for (var b = 0; b < len; b++) { 
    if ((b >= start_day_index) && (b <= end_day_index)) {

        var open_day_name_hour = short_days[b] + "_open";
        var close_day_name_hour = short_days[b] + "_close";

        open_name_days[open_day_name_hour] = start_time;
        open_name_days[close_day_name_hour] = end_time;

    }
  }  
}

console.log(open_name_days);
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to first format the date string to something more comprehensible by the computer (more standardize), then you can just rip off the parts you need very easily:

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/8L5EA/

The following code will modify your date string into a standardized format:

```
["monday+tuesday+wednesday+thursday+friday06:00-20:00"]
["monday+wednesday+friday12:00-21:00"]
["monday+tuesday+wednesday+thursday+sunday11:00-20:00"]
["monday11:00-20:30", "tuesday11:00-20:30", "wednesday11:00-20:30", "thursday11:00-20:30", ""]

[ d[+d...]HH:MM-HH:MM , d[+d...]HH:MM-HH:MM , ... ]
```

And then it will create objects based on this standardized string.

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/8L5EA/

```
console.log(makeObj(txt));  //<-- Here is your object

function makeObj(txt) {
    arr = formatText(txt);
    var result = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var times = arr[i].match(/\d\d:\d\d-\d\d:\d\d/);
        if (times === null) {
            continue;
        }
        times = times[0].split("-");
        var days = arr[i].match(/(\D+)\d\d:\d\d-\d\d:\d\d/)[1].split("+");
        for (var j = 0; j < days.length; j++) {
            result[days[j] + "_open"] = times[0];
            result[days[j] + "_close"] = times[1];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

function addZeros(n) {
    return ("0" + n).slice(-2);
};

function formatText(txt) {
    //remove spaces
    var output = txt.replace(/\s/g, "");
    //change abbr. to full name
    output = output.toLowerCase().replace(/(mon|tues|tue|wed|thurs|thur|thu|fri|sat|sun)(?![a-z])/g, function (c) {
        return {
            mon: "monday",
            tue: "tuesday",
            tues: "tuesday",
            wed: "wednesday",
            thu: "thursday",
            thur: "thursday",
            thurs: "thursday",
            fri: "friday",
            sat: "saturday",
            sun: "sunday"
        }[c];
    });
    //change "comma" day intervals to "plus"
    var daysInt = /(monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday),(monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday)/g;
    while (daysInt.test(output)) {
        output = output.replace(daysInt, "$1+$2");
    }
    //remove comma after days declarations
    output = output.replace(/(monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday)\,/g, "$1");
    //change intervals into using "plus"
    output = output.replace(/(monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday)-(monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday)/g, function (c) {
        var days = ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday", "sunday"],
            opt = [],
            interval = c.split("-");
        interval[0] = days.indexOf(interval[0]);
        interval[1] = days.indexOf(interval[1]);
        interval[0] -= interval[1] < interval[0] ? 7 : 0;
        while (true) {
            opt.push(days[interval[0] < 0 ? interval[0] + 7 : interval[0]]);
            interval[0]++;
            if (interval[0] > interval[1]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        opt = opt.join("+");
        return opt;
    });

    //turn 12-hour format to 24-hour format
    output = output.replace(/(\D)(\d)(?!\d)/g, "$10$2");
    output = output.replace(/([^:])(\d\d)(am|pm)/g, "$1$2:00$3");
    output = output.replace(/\d\d:\d\d(am|pm)/g, function (c) {
        if (c.indexOf("pm") == -1) {
            return c == "12:00am" ? "00:00" : c.replace("am", "");
        } else {
            c = c.replace("pm", "");
            return c == "12:00" ? "12:00" : addZeros((+c.substr(0, 2) + 12)) + c.slice(2);
        }
    });

    //split different times
    output = output.split(/[,;]/);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. I think I'll take this approach. Standardize the string first, then use some pattern matching from there. It should be noted that there is an error in your code. The first replace will take "Monday" and replace it with "mondayday".

Comment: @LeviRoberts - Yea, there are *some* errors, but the most important part is the concept itself. I am fixing those errors right now, as well as handling intervals. (PS: It is fixed now.)

Comment: I'm curious if you can Regex exact match UNTIL. For example, regex until non alphabet character. This will only pick things up like mon_, mon; mon, and leave things like monday alone.

Comment: @LeviRoberts - Why would you need that?

Comment: @LeviRoberts - `/mon(?!day).*?(?=[^a-z])?/`

Comment: I was thinking `var day_match = str.match(/([a-zA-Z]+)/)[0];`. Which will find all text at the beginning until not a-z. Then do a strict replace `if only mon -> replace with monday`. Or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: @LeviRoberts - Actually, if you look into my code, there is a part where I replace all "monday" abbreviations to `monday`. (I've added comments)

Comment: I just think it feels sloppy to replace the text (ie; abbreviate `mon`) regardless if it is `monday`, then later go back and fix it. I'd like a `regex replace` of this sort: `str.match(/mon|tue(?!day).*?(?=[^a-z])?/);` But I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: @LeviRoberts - But my code doesn't "go back and fix it". It will match  `mon` only if it is not `monday`.

Comment: @LeviRoberts - Okay, I have finished the final version. All string will be standardized into this format: `d[+d...]HH:MM-HH:MM` (`d` is day of week.) Enjoy and don't forget you can accept this answer if this helps you.

Comment: You are correct that it only compares `mon`. Perhaps I was wrong in thinking that would be the best solution. I've been learning regex using regex101.com debugger. I think comparing mon#,mond,monda,monday etc is the best solution. You can do that with this regex:
`(mon|tues|tue|wed|thurs|thur|thu|fri|sat|sun).*?(?=[^a-z])` and it will still work properly.

Comment: @LeviRoberts - It will now return you the object you want, with string in whatever format you enter! http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/8L5EA/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46801/discussion-between-derek--and-levi-roberts)